# Sorting nodes, based on property value in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Basically I want to sort between various nodes and return one latest, whose property is true.. but if true is not present, I should get latest node having false property.
for e.g.
**nodeA** - > having property **renamed** value is **true**
**nodeB** - > having property **renamed** value is **false**

now the scenario is, there could be n number of nodes with property **renamed** as **true** and **false**, I want just latest one (node also have property of time in millisecond format) with property of true if not true then latest false.

is there any way to achieve this using cypher query ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the latest node with the property "renamed" value of "true", then you can first sort the nodes by the property "renamed" and then the property "time" in descending order, and take the first one,

```
Match somenode:Something
Return somenode
Order by somenode.renamed DESC, somenode.time DESC 
limit 1
```

If there are nodes with the property "renamed" value of "true", then the first one must be the  latest one of all nodes with the value "true"; if there are no nodes with the value of "true", then the first one must be the latest one of all nodes with the value of "false".

Answer (score -1):

```
START a=node(*) 
MATCH p=a-[*1..]->b 
WHERE ALL (x IN nodes(p) 
           WHERE x.renamed=true OR (id(x)=id(b) AND x.renamed=false)) 
RETURN p
```

all nodes except the last one `b` must have `renamed=false` and the last one `b` must have `renamed=false`